# How to simulate a simple light sensor in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to simulate a simple [Lego NXT light sensor](http://shop.lego.com/Product/Default.aspx?p=9844) in Gazebo? Is there already some existing photodetector Gazebo plugin? If not, what rough steps would you propose?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10175/how-to-simulate-a-simple-light-sensor-in-gazebo?/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this is overkill, or if there is something simpler, but I'd modify the camera sensor code, and either adjust it to a single pixel, or do averaging over many, and publish intensity instead of an image.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using a modified camera is definitely a good idea. You should look at the specification of your light sensor, and determine how it behaves in the real world (sensitivity, range, field-of-view, etc).

I would then right a simple shader to attach to the camera (look at the StereoCamera for an example). The shader should fill a texture with light intensity. Right now the StereoCamera has a shader that fills a texture with depth data. You can use this as a starting point, and google should tell you how to compute light intensity in GLSL.

If the above seems overkill, or too much work. Then you can write a sensor that just iterates over all the lights in the world, and computes distance to the sensor. This will have some drawbacks: occlusions and reflections are problematic.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 431 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3